# Why do i see escape sequence characters in the parse output for cheerio?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

Attached below is my code:-

```
app.get("/techcrunch", (req, res) => {
    axios("https://techcrunch.com/")
      .then((response) => {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html, {decodeEntities: false });
        const newsItems = [];
  
        $("h2.post-block__title").each(function () {
          // const title = $(this).text()
          const baseElement = $(this);
          const title = baseElement.text();
          const url = baseElement.find("a").attr("href");
          newsItems.push({ title, url});
        });
        res.send(newsItems);
  
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  });
```

Over here I'm trying to parse the page source of TechCrunch and extract the text stored in "h2.post-block__title" but weirdly in the resultant string I see escape sequence characters like "\n" , "\t" and so on as seen below:-

```
 {
    "title": "\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tThis Week in Apps: Instagram brings back the chronological feed, South Korea bans P2E games, Google looks for ecosystem integrations\t\t\t\n\t\t",
    "url": "https://www.bbc.comhttps://techcrunch.com/2022/01/08/this-week-in-apps-instagram-brings-back-the-chronological-feed-south-korea-bans-p2e-games-google-looks-for-ecosystem-integrations/"
  },
```

I tried passing {decodeEntities: false} as seen above but it still does not return it.

One way to solve it, i thought would be to run unescape() on the title string returned by cheerio but unfortunately unescape() is deprecated i guess.

Any idea on what i could do? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not sure where you see that, but that's either JSON or a JavaScript object literal. In these formats, that's the proper encoding for literal line feeds and tabs, so that'd be the expected and correct output, and it shouldn't cause any issue.

Comment: thank you so much for replying back. After reading your comment, I built a card component and rendered it in the frontend and it works flawlessly. Didn't think the output would have come correct looking at the json backend results. Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Trim the whitespace: `const title = baseElement.text().trim();`